# Making multiple GET requests in retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a requirement where I want to make multiple GET requests, what will be best practice in java not using RxJava.

Here I have given parameter as i in getPhotos(), specifies id which loads data in json accordingly. This can run concurrently.

```java
PhotoList list = UnplashClient.getUnplashClient().create(PhotoList.class);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            call = list.getPhotos(i);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have heard about dispatcher, but how that works. How shall I queue those requests?

Comment: You're doing same api call with same value. That might return same response everytime. What is the purpose of this? What you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more specifics? Are you looking for making multiple calls in serial?

Comment: @EldhoseMBabu,  I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for serial execution of api calls one after the other, you can make use of [Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task). This is similar to what Rx java is doing.

Please find the pseudo code below with an example :

```
private void fetchPhotos() {
    Task<Photo> task = null;
    List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (task == null) {
            task = getPhoto(i);
        } else {
            final int pos = i;
            task = task.onSuccessTask(photo -> {
                photos.add(photo);
                return getPhoto(pos);
            });
        }
    }

    task.addOnCompleteListener((photoTask) -> {
        photos.add(photoTask.getResult()); //Adding the final result.
        for (int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("DEMO", photos.get(i).toString());
        }
    });
}

private Task<Photo> getPhoto(int i) {
    Task<Photo> task = Tasks.call(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() /*You can specify the threading here*/, () -> new Photo(i) /*Your logic to fetch photo goes here...*/);
    return task;
}

class Photo {

    int pos = 0;

    Photo(int p) {
        this.pos = p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(pos);
    }
}
```

Running above code, you can see result in sequential order printed in Logcat. Here the chaining of requests happens from the success of previous request.